# Can't login to admin site. Returns a page not found error

Tags: python, django, django-admin, hosting, cpanel

I am trying to host my website at a2hosting shared hosting plan. I was told to use cpanel to create a virtualenv and then, use passenger to run django. My virtualenv folder and project folder are in the root directory. After setting everything and running collectstatic and creating a superuser, I tried going to the django admin site. I get the login page, however, trying to login results in a page not found error. It states:

> Page not found (404)
>
> Request Method:   POST
>
> Request URL:  https://www.website.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
>
> Raised by:    django.contrib.admin.sites.login
>
> Using the URLconf defined in readerspoint.urls, Django tried these URL
>   patterns, in this order:
>
> 1) admin/
>
> The empty path didn't match any of these.
>
> You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django
>   settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a
>   standard 404 page.

I trired looking at the CPanel errors, here is what it states:

> WARNING: /home/username/public_html/admin/login: Can't access file
>   /home/username/public_html/admin/login: No such file or directory
>
> WARNING: /home/username/public_html/admin/login: Can't access file
>   /home/username/public_html/admin/login: No such file or directory
>
> WARNING: /home/username/public_html/admin: Can't access file
>   /home/username/public_html/admin: No such file or directory
>
> [ N 2018-02-28 18:53:10.6076 766038/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:994 ]:
>   Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process
>   830971, application /home/username/website
>
> [ N 2018-02-28 18:53:10.4069 766038/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:994 ]:
>   Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process
>   836756, application /home/username/public_html
>
> [ N 2018-02-28 18:53:10.4067 766038/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:994 ]:
>   Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process
>   835949, application /home/username/public_html
>
> [ N 2018-02-28 18:53:10.3932 766038/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:994 ]:
>   Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process
>   836756, application /home/username/public_html
>
> [ N 2018-02-28 18:53:10.3930 766038/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:994 ]:
>   Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process
>   835949, application /home/username/public_html
>
> [ N 2018-02-28 18:53:10.3928 766038/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:994 ]:
>   Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process
>   830971, application /home/username/website
>
> [ N 2018-02-28 18:49:24.1637 766038/Tt age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:994 ]:
>   Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process
>   790124, application /home/username/public_html
>
> [ N 2018-02-28 18:48:35.3971 766038/Tr age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:994 ]:
>   Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process
>   787169, application /home/username/website
>
> [ N 2018-02-28 18:40:57.7578 766038/T9 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:994 ]:
>   Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process
>   780233, application /home/username/website
>
> [ N 2018-02-28 18:37:16.8870 607641/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:994 ]:
>   Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process
>   686858, application /home/username/public_html
>
> [ N 2018-02-28 18:37:16.8766 607641/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:994 ]:
>   Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process
>   686858, application /home/username/public_html

**URLconf** of my the project currently looks like:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank You

Comment: Please show us your URLconf (usually located in `projectname/urls.py`).

Comment: I haven't made any changes to my project yet. I have the project in my local machine. I wanted to see if everything was working fine on the hosting site but then, I ran into this problem. I have updated the question with the file's content.

Comment: URLconf looks OK. This should work in Django. This CPanel error: `WARNING: /home/username/public_html/admin/login: Can't access file /home/username/public_html/admin/login: No such file or directory` throws me off, because it appears that the webserver actually tries to locate a file on the disk and return that file. That is not how Django works, so maybe the webserver is misconfigured? It's hard to judge, but I would say this is not a Django problem.

Comment: Hey, that's exactly what I thought and had previously contacted a2hosting about the issue. However, they seemed to think that it's a fault with the django files. I did a bit of experimenting and copied all the admin and auth files from site_packages and into the public_html. I seemed to be able to login after that. However, that project had different apps and I wasn't able to add anything using the django site(only through my own forms). This wasn't true for all forms as one of them wasn't working and gave me a page not found with similar cpanel error.

Comment: So, I have contacted them again and they are telling me that I am unable to use admin site as I don't have the files in the public_html folder. I am not sure if that's really the solution.

Comment: Hello @Tanvir Ahmed. I am having the same issue "coincidently" in an  a2hosting shared hosting plan. Can you tell me if you could find a solution?

Comment: Hey, sorry hope I am not too late to reply. I was unable to find any fixes. What I assume is that their configuration has some errors somewhere regarding the public_html file. However, I did get to host my website by changing to vps and setting everything up. (Check out blogs by digitalocean if you need help). It took a few hours and with two tries, I was able to get everything up and running. Hope it helps!

Comment: A solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50827230/1198074

Comment: I have setup Django project on go daddy channel , i am able to open only www.exapmle.com , but www.example.com/admin or www.example.com/aboutus gives 404. can anyone help