# Django trying to match wrong url path

Tags: python, django

Trying to deploy my Django app on virtual shared server. All works as expected until I try to log in to the admin app. I think it may have something to do with the way that the server deals with posts (had a similar problem with Flask). The setup works fine on my local machine.

I can get to the admin login page, but when I submit my credentials I get a 404 error. In debug mode the response is:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    https://lindcraft.williesworkshop.com/admin/login/
Raised by:  django.contrib.admin.sites.login
Using the URLconf defined in lindcraft.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
admin/
^[P|p]roducts?/(?P<prod_id>\d{0,3})/$ [name='product']
^[P|p]rices?/?$ [name='prices']
^[P|p]arking [name='parkingIntro']
^[D|d]isplay [name='displayIntro']
^[C|c]ontact [name='contact']
^[A|a]bout [name='about']
^$ [name='index']
The current path, login/, didn't match any of these.
```

The project urls.py is:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', include('www.urls')),]
```

Django seems to be looking for "login/" instead of "admin/" even though the "request URL" is "... /admin/login/" The admin part is striped off somehow.

Funny thing is, the exception seems to be raised by django.contrib.admin.sites.login as though the request actually made it to admin.

It seems to me that the same URL works with a GET but not with a POST.

Can anyone offer any insight?

FWIW, my hosting service (a2hosing) uses something called passenger to manage python requests. There may, or may not be a ngnix server used too.

TIA!

Comment: Show us the contents of `lindcraft.urls` and the full stack trace for the error please.

Comment: I added the urls.py content. I don't know how to get a stack trace. The 404 page did not include any more information. I did just check the stderr log, and there is nothing there about this.

Comment: Your urlconf looks fine. This appears to be an issue with your hosting service provider - someone else has exactly the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49028254/cant-login-to-admin-site-returns-a-page-not-found-error